# jquery filtering using .indexOf() table based a 2 parameters

Tags: jquery

I have a large table something like this below. I want to filter the table by Office and Month. I was thinking to do this I would some how use .indexOf() twice. I tried to do this in different ways and did not figure it out.

| Office | Name | Month | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1a | Abe D | Jan | 10 |
| 1a | Abe D | Feb | 13 |
| 1a | Abe D | Mar | 11 |
| 1a | Abe D | Apr | 12 |
| 1a | Jon R | Jan | 9 |
| 1a | Jon R | Feb | 12 |
| 1a | Jon R | Mar | 9 |
| 1a | Jon R | Apr | 13 |
| 2b | Eve C | Jan | 13 |
| 2b | Eve C | Feb | 14 |
| 2b | Eve C | Mar | 13 |
| 2b | Eve C | Apr | 15 |

This is what I tried.

```
    let office = "1a";
    let mth = "Jan";
    $("#Table2 tbody tr").filter(function() {
    let step1 = $(this).toggle($(this).text().indexOf(office) > -1);
    $(step1).toggle($(step1).text().indexOf(mth) > -1);
    });
```

The code does not yield what I want. Below is what I want the output to be.

| Office | Name | Month | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1a | Abe D | Jan | 10 |
| 1a | Jon R | Jan | 9 |

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would do it.

```js
let drpOffice = $('#drpOffice');
let drpMonth = $('#drpMonth');
let trs = $("#Table2 tbody tr");

function filterTable() {
  trs.show();
  trs.each(function() {
    let tr = $(this);
    let officeVal = tr.find('td:nth-child(1)').text();
    let monthVal = tr.find('td:nth-child(3)').text();

    if (officeVal !== drpOffice.val() || monthVal !== drpMonth.val()) {
      tr.hide();
    }
  });
}

$(window).on('load', filterTable);
drpOffice.on('change', filterTable);
drpMonth.on('change', filterTable);
```

```css
button {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
thead {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label for="#drpOffice">Office</label>
<select id="drpOffice">
  <option>1a</option>
  <option>2b</option>
</select>

<label for="#drpMonth">Month</label>
<select id="drpMonth">
  <option>Jan</option>
  <option>Feb</option>
  <option>Mar</option>
  <option>Apr</option>
  <option>May</option>
  <option>Jun</option>
  <option>Jul</option>
  <option>Aug</option>
  <option>Sep</option>
  <option>Dec</option>
  <option>Oct</option>
  <option>Dec</option>
</select>

<table id="Table2">
  <thead>
    <tr><th>Office</th><th>Name</th><th>Month</th><th>Sales</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>1a</td><td>Abe D</td><td>Jan</td><td>10</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1a</td><td>Abe D</td><td>Feb</td><td>13</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1a</td><td>Abe D</td><td>Mar</td><td>11</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1a</td><td>Abe D</td><td>Apr</td><td>12</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1a</td><td>Jon R</td><td>Jan</td><td>9</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1a</td><td>Jon R</td><td>Feb</td><td>12</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1a</td><td>Jon R</td><td>Mar</td><td>9</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1a</td><td>Jon R</td><td>Apr</td><td>13</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2b</td><td>Eve C</td><td>Jan</td><td>13</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2b</td><td>Eve C</td><td>Feb</td><td>14</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2b</td><td>Eve C</td><td>Mar</td><td>13</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2b</td><td>Eve C</td><td>Apr</td><td>15</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I modified the code slightly because the office and month are drop down lists. The problem I am having it that the same office and month keep showing up even after I change it on the drop down list month and office. It appears that what ever I pick first stays in the memory.

Comment: Oh, well in that case you could have a listener on the dropdowns that shows all the `tr`s in the table before it filters them.

Comment: I've updated my answer to have office and month dropdowns.

Answer (score 1):

@JosephWebber already provided a good solution based on jQuery. Here is another one in Vanilla JavaScript.

```js
const sels=["drpOffice","drpMonth"].map(id=>document.getElementById(id));
const trs = [...document.querySelectorAll("#Table2 tbody tr")];

function filterTable() {
 const [off,mon]=sels.map(s=>s.value);
 trs.forEach(tr=>tr.style.display=(!off||tr.children[0].textContent==off)&&(!mon||tr.children[2].textContent==mon)?"":"none");
}

window.onload=filterTable;
sels.forEach(s=>s.addEventListener('change', filterTable));
```

```css
button {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
thead {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<label for="#drpOffice">Office</label>
<select id="drpOffice">
  <option></option>
  <option>1a</option>
  <option>2b</option>
</select>

<label for="#drpMonth">Month</label>
<select id="drpMonth">
  <option></option>
  <option>Jan</option>
  <option>Feb</option>
  <option>Mar</option>
  <option>Apr</option>
  <option>May</option>
  <option>Jun</option>
  <option>Jul</option>
  <option>Aug</option>
  <option>Sep</option>
  <option>Dec</option>
  <option>Oct</option>
  <option>Dec</option>
</select>

<table id="Table2">
  <thead>
    <tr><th>Office</th><th>Name</th><th>Month</th><th>Sales</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>1a</td><td>Abe D</td><td>Jan</td><td>10</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1a</td><td>Abe D</td><td>Feb</td><td>13</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1a</td><td>Abe D</td><td>Mar</td><td>11</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1a</td><td>Abe D</td><td>Apr</td><td>12</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1a</td><td>Jon R</td><td>Jan</td><td>9</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1a</td><td>Jon R</td><td>Feb</td><td>12</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1a</td><td>Jon R</td><td>Mar</td><td>9</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1a</td><td>Jon R</td><td>Apr</td><td>13</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2b</td><td>Eve C</td><td>Jan</td><td>13</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2b</td><td>Eve C</td><td>Feb</td><td>14</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2b</td><td>Eve C</td><td>Mar</td><td>13</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2b</td><td>Eve C</td><td>Apr</td><td>15</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```